# Accessing pedometer in UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, pedometer

Here's [pedometer sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Pedometer) for UWP. It works fine on my phone.

However, in my custom app, I cannot get it to determine whether the pedometer device can be accessed. It always gives me `DeviceAccessStatus.Unspecified` status.

Here's the standard code:

```
// Common class ID for pedometers
Guid PedometerClassId = new Guid("B19F89AF-E3EB-444B-8DEA-202575A71599"); 

// Determine if we can access pedometers
var deviceAccessInfo = DeviceAccessInformation.CreateFromDeviceClassId(PedometerClassId);
if (deviceAccessInfo.CurrentStatus == DeviceAccessStatus.Allowed)
{}
```

What I may be missing here, guys? Same happens on device that supports Pedometer and on one that doesn't.

I've compared both project manifest files, etc.

If I skip this check, then later on I get `Access denied` exception when trying to run `viewModel.Pedometer = await Pedometer.GetDefaultAsync();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you specified the `Device` capability in the `Package.appxmanifest`?

```
<Capabilities>
   <DeviceCapability Name="activity" />
</Capabilities>
```

It is [present in the sample's manifest](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/Pedometer/cs/Package.appxmanifest) (line 58), it is probably required to be able to access the device. The `AccessDeniedException` seems to support this.

Comment: That was it, @Martin! I haven't compared manifests code wise and therefore have missed that line. Strange that I never come to this requirement before :) Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped :-)! Happy coding!

Comment: I was trying to access pedometer class but my code was not working. after adding this line, my code is working now but  I still don't know how it is working?